Using single-integral to evaluate the area enclosed by $y^2=2x$ and the line $x-y=4$.

Find the area enclosed by $y^2=2x$ and the line $x-y=4$.

To solve this problem, I used double integrals. Here is the graph of the region that we wish to evaluate its area:

$$\int_{-2}^4\int_{\frac{y^2}2}^{y+4}dxdy=\int_{-2}^{4}(y+4-\dfrac{y^2}2)dy=18$$
I'm wondering if it is possible to solve this problem using single-integral.

Yes, it's possible

Hint: reflect across the line $y=x$ and the area is the difference of $2$ simple integrals.

@agent_cracker103 I got it thanks.

Your $y$-integral is precisely what you want, the area between the curves $x(y)=y+4$ and $x(y)=\frac{y^2}2$

So here we want to solve this question using only a single integral
$ y^2 = 2x $ and $x-y=4$

Now we have to find out the area enclosed by these curves
So we want is OADB
Area of OAC = $ \int_{0}^{8} \sqrt{2x} \, dx $=$64/3$
Area of triangle ADC = 8
Area of OEB = $ \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{2x} \, dx $ = $8/3$
Area of Triangle EDB = 2
Required Area = Ar(OAC) + Ar(OEB) + Ar(EDB) -Ar(ADC)
Required Area = $\frac{64}{3} + \frac83 + 2 - 8$ = $18$

Given :
$y^{2}=2x$ and $x-y=4$
Now from the graph it is clear that first of all you have to find the intersection point.
Let's find the intersection point first.
$$y^{2}=2x$$
$$\implies (x-4)^{2}=2x$$ because from the $2^{nd}$ equation we get $y=(x-4)$.
$$\implies x^{2}-8x+16=2x$$
$$\implies x^{2}-(8+2)x+16=0$$
$$\implies x^{2}-8x-2x+16=0$$
$$\implies (x-8)(x-2)=16$$
Therefore $x=${$2,8$}
Again, let's find $y$.
That is we know that $y=(x-4)$.
$$\implies y=-2$$ when $x=2$
and $$y=4$$ when $x=8$.
Therefore let's find out the area in terms of $y$. That is
Required Area : $$\int_{-2}^{4}\left[\frac{y^{2}}{2}-(y+4)\right]dy$$
$$=\int_{-2}^{4}\frac{y^{2}}{2}dy-\int_{-2}^{4}(y+4)dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{4}y^{2}dy\int_{-2}^{4}(y+4)dy$$
$$=\frac{72}{6}-\int_{-2}^{4}(y+4)dy$$
NOTE :
$\int y^{2}dy=\frac{y^{3}}{3}$
Now put the limits.
Again for the integral of $$\int_{-2}^{4}(y+4)dy$$ substitute $(y+4)=t$
$$\implies dy=dt$$.
$$\int_{-2}^{4}(y+4)dx=\int_{2}^{8}tdt=\frac{64-4}{2}=30$$
$$\implies \int_{-2}^{4}[\frac{y^{2}}{2}-(y+4)]dx=(12-30)=-18$$
Now since area can't be negative
Therefore required area $= 18 units^{2}$.
